# Javascript "this" value gets lost when trying to access its values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

[image]

As you see in the image above, the value of `this`.

However when I try to access its values like `this.swipeCard`, the value gets undefined as seen on the next image.

[image]

Not sure what's happening but any ideas would be very helpful.

Thanks~

Comment: Could you update your question to include a [mcve]? I'd recommend using a stacksnippet (click `<>` when editing the question).

Comment: Adding code instead of screenshot is better.

Comment: arrow functions [don't bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) `this` - they share the enclosing scope.

Comment: Switch back to es5 notation (ie not arrow functions) and it should function as you expect.

Comment: @rrd Your advice works. I'm contented for now. 
Emissary It's a good read.

Thanks guys.